# Unable to read the content from a non-empty InputStream

Tags: java, buffer, inputstream

I have a piece of code that reads the content from a non-empty InputStream. However, it works fine in Eclipse and using ant script in my computer, but it fails in an another computer, the result is an empty String, I have checked, the the InputStream is not null. The inputstream is reading a local file, and the file is not empty.

Here are the two different ways I have tried, both of them return an empty String:

Way 1:

```
StringBuilder aStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

String strLine = null;

BufferedReader aBufferedReaders = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(anInputStream, "UTF-8"));

while ((strLine = aBufferedReaders.readLine()) != null)
{
  aStringBuilder.append(strLine);
}

return aStringBuilder.toString()
```

Way 2:

```
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

byte[] b = new byte[4096];

for (int n; (n = theInputStream.read(b)) != -1;)
{
  buffer.append(new String(b, 0, n));
}

String str = buffer.toString();

return str;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see any difference between way 1 and way2. Same code, but different variable names. You shouldn't be using streams to read text. Use readers.

Comment: Pretty sure that the problem is not related to this code but to the environment. Is the stream connected to a file, a remote resource (web) or something else?

Comment: The first way is correct, except it removes all the newlines from the read text. I agree with Andreas_D.

Comment: @Andreas_D The stream is connected to a local file

Comment: @IKEFORWARD - then I simply guess that there's a problem with *that* file or the expected file location on *the other machine*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input stream can be non-null but still *empty* - and if no exceptions are being thrown but an empty string is being returned, then the input stream *is* empty. You should look at the code which is opening the input stream in the first place - the code to read from the stream isn't the source of the error, although you need to decide which encoding you're trying to read, and use that appropriately. (The first code looks better to me, explicitly using UTF-8 and using an `InputStreamReader` for text conversion.)